# How to Send formatted mail body Unix Script

Tags: linux, email, shell, unix

I would like to format the mail content before I send, Below is my code,

```
echo "Time: `$TIMESTAMP_CMD\n\n$EMAIL_BODY" | mail -s "$EMAIL_SUBJECT" ${EMAIL_DIST}
```

`TIMESTAMP_CMD`,`EMAIL_BODY`, `EMAIL_SUBJECT` and `EMAIL_DIST` are variables which are defined above this code.

Here, I need line breaks between TIMESTAMP_CMD and EMAIL_BODY. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
printf "Time: $TIMESTAMP_CMD\n\n$EMAIL_BODY"
```

Also you use a back-tick in the `echo` which  invokes `shell`. But it seems `$TIMESTAMP_CMD` holds a shell command. So you'd want something like this,

```
printf "Time: `$TIMESTAMP_CMD`\n\n$EMAIL_BODY" 
# or
printf "Time: $($TIMESTAMP_CMD)\n\n$EMAIL_BODY" 
# or
printf "Time: %s\n\n$EMAIL_BODY" "$($TIMESTAMP_CMD)"
```

Comment: +1, but I think the backtick is not extraneous.  Rather, the closing backtick is missing and the OP wants printf "Time: %s\n\n%s" "$($TIMESTAMP_CMD)" "$EMAIL_BODY"

Comment: @William thanks. I should have guessed it. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to use `echo` then you can make use of `-e` switch to enable interpretation of backslash escapes something like `echo -e "Time: $TIMESTAMP_CMD\n\n$EMAIL_BODY"`. You can refer the man pages or this [link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) for more info. And as pointed out previously please get rid of the backtick (`) when `echo`ing.
Hope this helps!